# Sending one line of hash to method

Tags: ruby, hash, parameters

I have an array with words that I will use as keys. I iterate trough this array and put the words as keys and user input as value simplified like this:

```
input = Hash.new() 
array.each do |a|

  input[a] = gets.strip
end
```

for example array `["one", "twoo", "three"]`
and the user inputs first: three

I want to pass `{"one" => "three"}`
So the current key and value
Now I want to pass this "line" of the array to a method how do I do this ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to pass the hash to a method - `foo(input)`? Or do you want to pass the current value - `foo(input[a])`? Or something else. Could you add examples?

Comment: I want to pass both the current key and the current value i will ad an example! @ ndn

Comment: IF you explain what you are hoping to achieve as well as why you have chosen this method we will be in a far more adequate position to assist

Comment: @FroggyFreshh Did you check my answer?  is it useful?

Answer (score 1):

It is still unclear what you want to achieve. The way I see it, you can mean one of three things:

- *"I want to pass the key and value after the user enters them to a method"*

  ```
  array.each do |key|
    input[key] = gets.strip
    my_method(key, input[key])
  end
  ```
- A possible spin on that is *"But I want to pass them as a single hash"*

  ```
  array.each do |key|
    input[key] = gets.strip
    my_method({key, input[key]})
  end
  ```
- *"I want to pass the entire hash after the user fills all the values"*

  ```
  array.each do |key|
    input[key] = gets.strip
  end
  my_method(input)
  ```

Comment: The last one is how I did it until now. The first and second options are more what i'm looking for! :) thnx alot!

Comment: Just a note that in #2 one can write `my_method(key=>input[key])`. Froggy, it's arguably more idiomatic to write `array.each_with_object({}) do |key, input|...`, which returns `input` (and drop `input = Hash.new`, aka `input={}`).

Answer (score 0):

Just call that method and pass your "line":

```
input = Hash.new() 

array.each do |a|
  input[a] = gets.strip

  # Send a line that user has inputed
  your_method(input[a])

  # Send key and the line that user has inputed
  your_method(a, input[a])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an impression that you are not trying to pass the entire hash at a time. If so, here is the one line answer

```
arr.each{|x| my_method({x => gets.strip})}
```

If I am wrong and you want to pass it at a time. Here is the one line answer

```
my_method(Hash[arr.zip(arr.map{gets.strip})])
```